# Passing arguments to xlconnect functions with ellipses

Tags: r, xlconnect

I have a bunch of excel files in one folder, and would like to write a single function as follows:

```
# takes a file path and sheetname for an excel workbook, passes on additional params
getxl_sheet <- function(wb_path, sheetname, ...) {
  testbook <- XLConnect::loadWorkbook(wb_path)
  XLConnect::readWorksheet(testbook, sheet = sheetname, ...)
}
```

However, when I run the following,

```
set.seed(31415)
x <- rnorm(15); y <- rnorm(15)
randvals <- data.frame(x=x, y=y)
XLConnect::writeWorksheetToFile("~/temp_rands.xlsx", randvals, "Sheet1")
my_vals <- getxl_sheet("~/temp_rands.xlsx", "Sheet1", endRow=5)
```

my_vals returns the entire 15 by 2 dataframe, as opposed to just stopping at the fifth row (likewise if I use 'endCol=1' for example, it gives both columns). On the other hand, passing additional arguments in base R hasn't been a problem:

```
my_plot <- function(...) {
  plot(...)
}
#my_plot(x=x, y=y, pch=16, col="blue")
```

works as expected. What's the problem with the function defined above to read in xlsx files? Thanks.

devtools::session_info()
Session info---------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value
 version  R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10)
 system   x86_64, darwin13.1.0
 ui       RStudio (0.98.1062)
 language (EN)
 collate  en_US.UTF-8
 tz       America/New_York

Packages-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package       * version    date       source
 devtools        1.6.0.9000 2014-11-26 Github (hadley/devtools@bd9c252)
 rJava           0.9.6      2013-12-24 CRAN (R 3.1.0)
 rstudioapi      0.1        2014-03-27 CRAN (R 3.1.0)
 XLConnect     * 0.2.9      2014-08-14 CRAN (R 3.1.1)
 XLConnectJars * 0.2.9      2014-08-14 CRAN (R 3.1.1)

Comment: Look at the function code or the usage section of the help page. `readWorksheet` does not have a mechanism for handling `...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dots mechanism needs to have a function that expects dots, and unlike `plot.default`, `readWorksheet` is not designed to handle an ellipsis: You need to build some decoding into the arguments:

```
getxl_sheetRCshort <- function(wb_path, sheetname, ...) {
  arglist <- list(...)
  testbook <- loadWorkbook(wb_path);
  readWorksheet(testbook, sheet = sheetname, 
                endRow=arglist[['endRow']], endCol=arglist[['endCol']])
}

> my_vals <- getxl_sheet("~/temp_rands.xlsx", "Sheet1", endRow=5)
> my_vals
           x           y
1  1.6470129 -1.27323204
2 -1.1119872 -1.77141948
3 -1.5485456  1.40846809
4 -0.7483785 -0.09450125
```

You could make this even more general by doing matching on the entire `formals()` list from the `readWorksheet` function and there are worked examples in SO that illustrate this. Fortunately the parser is somehow able to ignore the fact that no value is passed to 'endCol'.